# Routes to images in Symfony 2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, gallery

I try to use [Bootstrap Thumbnail Gallery](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/thumbnail-gallery/) with Symfony 2, in template I write something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
      <a class="thumbnail" href='<img src="{{ asset("uploads/car_photos/" ~ carPhotos.path) }}" alt=""/>'>
           <img src="{{ asset('uploads/car_photos/' ~ carPhotos.path) }}" width="200" height="100" alt=""/>
      </a>
 </div>
```

In my browser, I get two equals pathes:

```
<img src="/uploads/car_photos/b5d8d11dae317ad488f0d2f88fc9b42ec40de103.jpeg" alt=""/>
```

But when I click on the image, I get the next error:

```
No route found for "GET /user/car/show/%3Cimg%20src=%22/uploads/car_photos/b5d8d11dae317ad488f0d2f88fc9b42ec40de103.jpeg%22%20alt=%22%22/%3E" (from "http://ontheway/app_dev.php/user/car/show/1")
```

Please help me, I am new in Symfony 2 and dont know all features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put an image tag in the `href` of your anchor tag, you cannot do that.

Try this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
      <a class="thumbnail" href='{{ asset("uploads/car_photos/" ~ carPhotos.path) }}'>
           <img src="{{ asset('uploads/car_photos/' ~ carPhotos.path) }}" width="200" height="100" alt=""/>
      </a>
</div>
```